# Function to create an identifier-like string out of one or two string in C

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

I'd like to know if there is a function in C to create an ID-like string ("account") from a string ("name") or two strings ("name", "surname") passed by argument.

The point is that I want to create an account with a pseudo-surname.
Any ideas to help me?

If there is no function to do that, I'd like to know the better way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: This is for code generation ?

Comment: Actually is for creating account. For example, my name is Michele Campus, and I have 2 char* name= "michele", surname= "campus". I wanto to generate a 3rd char* account with a pseudo random mix of name and surname (for example m_campus, or mcampus, or whatever you want).

Comment: But what do account names have to do with C variable names?

Comment: Ok, probably I explained the problem not very well. But the point is what I have written on the comment above.

Comment: @Kyrol: So you want to create an identifier-like string out of one or more strings? Could you please rephrase your question accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable name are defined at compile time. You can't generate dynamically a variable name and reference it. If you want to achieve something similar you can implement a Map, where the key is a string with your variable name.

the code could be something like that:

```
//take a name and create a new entry in the map holding value of the given size
void create_variable_entry(char * name, void * value, int size);

//return a pointer to a previous inserted variable with name name. return NULL if variable doesn't exist
void * get_variable(char * name);
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to write your own function. Iterate over all characters in the string and build a variable name out of that. If the character is alphanumeric or underscore, you can keep it, otherwise you will have to choose a replacement character. Variables in C must begin with either an underscore or a letter, numbers at the beginning of a string have to be handled.

The tricky issue is that the scheme might produce duplicate variable names for the same strings (the transformation is very likely to be surjective, not bijective). So there is typically some mapping table to keep trace of and choose some extra chars to differentiate these duplicates.

Comment: the passed string will be known only at runtime while variable needs to be created before compilation,How will create a variable at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

The `C` language specification does not provide any function(s) to create/generate variable names based on the input string.

But you can write one!

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't really make any sense, variable names are simply there for the purpose of writing your code and *identifying* specific *things* for the compiler. Once your code is compiled, the variable names have no meaning (apart from when you're debugging and you have debugging symbols embedded into your binary). So no, there isn't a function.

If you want to be able to *look-up* items with the use of a user-specified "name", then perhaps some sort of **map**/dictionary structure would be helpful.